# Why are VPN activation tickboxes greyed out after creating them?

Tags: gnome, vpn

I have created a set of VPN profiles, those profiles are allowed to be started by all users and I set it so during creation.

I restarted the network manager, but in the GUI, they keep being greyed out; like this screenhot.

[image: screenhot]

I've tried adding my user to the network group, but the network group doesn't exist.
I am on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS, clean install.

Comment: It seems to have something to do with managed connections. Networkmanager won't work without them.

Comment: From memory:  I believe when NM greys something out it means there is a 3rd party app not installed. In this case it would be VPN software. I had the same a few years ago when a client of mine used cisco and I did not have that connected to NM.